# Pandas dataframe plot 's' argument

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the statement and I really don't understand the `s=` part.  I know it sets the area of the plot but is it taking the data from `pop_2007` and raising it to 1^6 to create the area ?

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='gdp_2007', y='lifeExp_2007', s=df['pop_2007']/1e6)
```

I'm trying to understand the area of a plot better and the `s=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 's' parameter in the pandas dataframe plot function is changing the size of the markers in your scatter plot. See these two outputs where I change the 's' value from 1 to 100. So right now, your plot is taking the value in the df['pop_2007'] column and dividing it by 1e6 to get your value for the marker size.

```
#Three lines to make our compiler able to draw:
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'Duration', y = 'Maxpulse', s=1)

plt.show()

#Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

[Plot with s=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYpsR.png)

```
#Three lines to make our compiler able to draw:
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'Duration', y = 'Maxpulse', s=100)

plt.show()

#Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

[Plot with s=100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HezJ.png)

Test it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/trypandas.asp?filename=demo_pandas_plot_scatter2